# APIM Outbound policy skips policy immediately following a delete policy

Tags: azure-api-management

**Task and expected outcome**

I have the following outbound policies in Azure API Management. The first removes a header if it exists and the second returns the Certificate expiration date/time (which I was using for testing).

**Problem**

There were several headers being removed initially, but I found that some of my custom outbound headers were disappearing.

It seems to be the policy immediately following the `delete` action that is being skipped. I have tried changing the order and the issue persists. I have also tried changing the delete action by adding a separate closing tag instead of self-closing, but that didn't work either.

I also removed and recreated the API from API Management and the issue remained.

**Code and question**

Is this due to a syntax error in my code?

```
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <set-header name="x-ms-workflow-name" exists-action="delete" />
        <set-header name="Certificate-Expiration" exists-action="override">
            <value>@{
                    var response = context.Request.Certificate.NotAfter;
                    return response.ToString();
                  }</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-header name="Certificate-Thumbprint" exists-action="override">
            <value>@{
                    var response = context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint;
                    return response.ToString();
                  }</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-header name="Certificate-Subject" exists-action="override">
            <value>@{
                    var response = context.Request.Certificate.PublicKey.Key.ToXmlString(false);
                    return response.ToString();
                  }</value>
        </set-header>
    </outbound>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it in my side, the policy `<set-header>` with `exists-action="delete"` and `exists-action="override"` work fine. The screenshot below is what I test in my side:
[image]

Your problem was caused by the code `var response = context.Request.Certificate.NotAfter`, `var response = context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint`, `var response = context.Request.Certificate.PublicKey.Key.ToXmlString(false);`. You need to check if `context.Request.Certificate` has `NotAfter`, `Thumbprint` and `PublicKey` first, then you can use them.

For example, when you want to use `var response = context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint;`, you need to check if `Thumbprint` exists. You can write the code like:
[image]